# Fastest way to traverse a DOM element tree in Javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to traverse a DOM select element that looks like this:

```
<select>
    <option value='1'>Text 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Text 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Text 3</option>
    <option value='4'>Text 4</option>
    . . .
    <option value='n'>Text n</option>
</select>
```

Such that `n` is greater than 10000 elements.  What is the most efficient way to get the contents of this DOM?

Comment: Define "get"? You have the contents right in front of you.

Comment: On a side note, you shouldn't be using a select list if it has 10000 elements - rethink your solution fella.

Comment: 10,000 elements in a select list? That's a lot of broken mouse wheels and aching fingers.

Comment: You might want to consider using a plugin like [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) that works like the tag system here, instead of having 10k options.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of selecting the elements depends on many factors.

> 1. The number of dom elements on the page.
> 2. The selector used to find the elements.
> 3. If you use id as a selector then it is the fastest among all other    selectors.
> 4. If you use attribute selectors depending on the dom elements you    might get slow results.

Coming to your example if you just use `$('select')` it will select all the `select` elements on the page but you need a specific element then give a unique id to it or a class name to find it using id or class name selector.